# Setting struct variables

Tags: web3js, contract-design

I am a total Solidity noob, and I want to know if I can use my set function to initialize my struct members as well as assign a value to a state variable:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract Govtcontract {

    uint256 public allocbudget;
    uint256 public rembudget;

    struct transaction{
        uint  expend;
        uint dept;
        string item;
        uint date;
        string location;
    }

 transaction public trx;


constructor (uint256 initbudget) public {
    allocbudget = initbudget;
    rembudget = initbudget;
}

function settx(uint amt, uint dep, string thing, uint date, string loc) public {
    trx.expend=amt;
    trx.dept=dep;
    trx.item=thing;
    trx.date=date;
    trx.location=loc;
    rembudget = rembudget - trx.expend;
}



function get() public constant returns (uint) {
    return rembudget;

    }
}
```

Also, how do I write the web3.js file to take multiple inputs for set()? I can't seem to find any resources online. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! You can validate this with Truffle:

1. Init project via `truffle init` and add your contract and deployment file
2. `truffle develop`
3. `compile`
4. `migrate`
5. `Govtcontract.deployed().then(instance => govt = instance.contract)`
6. `govt.settx(1000, 1000, "test", 1000, "test", { gas: 500000 })`

I arbitrarily set 500,000 because storing so many variables in one batch is not cheap in gas costs.

Optionally, you could try [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) or [EthFiddle](https://ethfiddle.com/) for contract compilation.